# Setting equal in Java: by value or reference?

Tags: java, string, list, reference

I did two tests, the first starting with `Strings`

```
    String str1 = "old";
    String str2 = str1;
    str1 = "new";

    System.out.println(str1); //new
    System.out.println(str2); //old
```

The above example indicates that `str2 = str1, by value`

Now I do the similar operations, but this time with `Lists`

```
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list2 = list1;
    list1.add(1);

    System.out.println(list1.size()); //1
    System.out.println(list2.size()); //1
```

This example indicates that `list2 = list1, by reference`

I am confused, `which Java variables/objects` are passed by `value` and which are passed by `reference`?

Comment: None are passed by reference, all are passed by value.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Why in the second example, list2 updates to have the same size as list1?

Comment: @onepiece cuz you are copying references

Comment: Keep in mind Strings are different in that they are immutable! :D

Comment: The difference is that `str1 = "new"` assigns a new object to a variable; but `list1.add(1)` modifies an existing object, without creating a new one.

Comment: Please keep in mind that when @SotiriosDelimanolis says everything is pass by value, this includes the value of reference variables (non-primitive variables only hold references). One of those things that is technically correct in Java but slightly misleading.

Comment: onepiece - all Java variables (other than primitives) are reference variables.  That means that whenever you use one, you're doing something to a reference.  It's not like C, where all variables are value variables.  What this means is that the distinction between "pass by reference" and "pass by value" doesn't exist in Java.  We pass by value, and it's references that get passed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first code, yes, this line

```
String str2 = str1;
```

Assigns `str2` to the same `String` referred by `str1`, that is, `"old"`. At this point, they are the same object. However, the next line

```
str1 = "new";
```

create a **new** instance of `String`, and changes the reference of `str1` to this new String. As we are changing the reference of `str1`, the content of `str2` are not changed.

Pay attention that Java, `String`s are immutable i.e. cannot change state once initialized. Thinking this way, content of `"old"` may never change. So when you assign `"new"` to `str1`, you don't change the value of `"old"`, you create a new `String` instead.

In other words, this line, in here, is the same as

```
str1 = new String("new");
```

http://i.minus.com/jboQoqCxApSELU.png

However, in the second code,

```
List<Integer> list2 = list1;
```

make `list2` refer to the same list as `list1`. As a result, `list1` and `list2` refer to the same list. Then

```
list1.add(1);
```

adds an element to the list referred by `list1`. However, as I have said, `list1` and `list2` refer to same list, both `list1` and `list2` now have the element `1`. There is no new instance created in the method call.

http://i.minus.com/jxDLyBqcUzgHZ.png

In fact, if you were to do

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list2 = list1;
list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(1);

System.out.println(list1.size()); //1
System.out.println(list2.size()); //0
```

because `list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();` reassigns `list1` to a new list, that no longer refer to the object referred by `list2`.

---

**After all** the assignment operator (i.e. `obj1 = obj2`) *always* copy the references, which two references will still refer to the same object instance after the assignment. This is for both `String`, `List`, or *any other classes* (But not primitive types).

However, `str1 = "new"` will, in most cases, create a new instance of `String` and then assign the reference to the new `String` to `str1` - this is a special case in the Java lanaguage. This don't apply to any other kind of objects. This is different to any other method call like `list1.add(1)`.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: When setting equal to another object, immutable objects create new instances of themselves, while mutable classes refer to the same thing unless they are instantiated manually (with the keyword `new`).

Comment: No!  That's not correct at all, @onepiece.  The whole mutable/immutable thing is completely irrelevant.  You could replace the `String` objects in your first code snippet with `List` objects, and you'd still see the same behaviour.

Comment: In fact, all assignment will refer to the same object. However, `str1 = "new";` is a special case in Java that will create a new `String` - which, in fact, made reasonable considering `String`s are immutable.

Comment: When setting equal, which objects behave like Strings and which behave like Lists?  For example, I am guessing that primitive types are like Strings, and most other classes (such as the JCF and self-written classes) behave like Lists.  `edit: actually, I just saw the diagrams and am trying to understand it.`

Comment: No!  You can create that first example using `List`.  It's not about any inherent difference between strings and lists.  It's about the difference between the assignment operator (`=`) and calling a method (like `add`).

Comment: @onepiece There are only 2 types. Primitives types and reference types. Don't think of it as `String` vs `List`. Both of those are reference types. They work the same way.

Comment: Yes! @DavidWallace Yes!

Comment: @luiges90 You can't change the value of the reference of a variable by invoking a method on that variable. David is absolutely right.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Sorry I was thinking something else and put a wrong comment. Yes, you have no way to change the value of reference of a variable by invoking a method on that variable

Answer (score 4):

Your difference is here

```
str1 = "new";
```

vs

```
list1.add(1);
```

In the `String` example, you are changing references. Changing the reference of `str1` does not affect any other variables.

In the `List` example, you are invoking a method, which dereferences the reference and accesses the object. Any variables referencing that same object will see that change.

Here it is

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // 1
List<Integer> list2 = list1; // 2 
list1.add(1); // 3
```

looks like this

```
   1:  list1 ===> object1234
   2:  list1 ===> object1234 <=== list2
   3:  list1 ===> object1234 (internal modification) <=== list2
```

Comment: "Any variables referencing that same object will see that change."

But if Java passes by value, list2 should have the value, not reference, of list1.

Comment: @onepiece The value is the reference.

Comment: @onepiece See step-by-step.

Comment: This answer is the clearest and most direct.  +1 for not mentioning "immutability", or for suggesting that Strings are somehow special.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in java is passed by Value.There nothing like pass by refrence in java.Objects reference is passed by value.
in ist case ie

```
String str1="old"
String str2=str1; //here str2 is pointed to str1
str1="new";       // here link of str1 is broken with old and pinted to new location      where as str2 is pointing to same location as earlier.
```

While in case of list both list are pointing to same memory location so changes are reflected.

Comment: Arrays are implicitly passed by reference in java. that is changes made to arrays in functions can reflect the original contents.

Answer (score 0):

Java is all pass by value.  There is no pass by reference with Java. A copy is passed to variables that could be method parameters or regular ordinary variables.  Objects such as String literals, Strings, Array references, and ArrayLists will still pass by value.

The thing is if the reference is not re-assigned then whatever happens to the reference variable will happen to the object it references.

Check out this tutorial on this from the people that wrote *head first java* and other books here: http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp

Also with your code, OP, keep in mind that Strings are immutable. This means once the object is created it will not change basically. In your code though the String references are re-assigned while the List reference simply has a method called on it. The List references both point to the exact same ArrayList object; so the method call `size()` effects both List references since they both point to the same object in heap memory. :D

Happy Coding!

Comment: That last paragraph is a red herring.  Even if `String` objects were not immutable, this particular example would still behave the same way.

Comment: Hi David. I read your comment in a New Zealand accent since you are from there. :D Anyway, you are probably right, without coding this on my machine and checking. This is because there was a re-assignment in with the String references unlike the List references. :D Thank-you for the feedback. I was so bored. :D

Comment: @DavidWallace I updated my answer. Thanks for the serious tip. :D

Comment: I don't feel your edit is an improvement.  I'm sorry, but I'm completely baffled by that last sentence.  I see only one `ArrayList` object, which is kind of the point of the question.

Comment: Oh right, again. I guess that would not even make sense if there were two java.util.ArrayList() objects. :D Thank-you again Mr. Wallace. :D