# Comparison of an old variable to a new one after some calculations

Tags: java, variables, encapsulation

```
variable1 = value_of_A;

for loop {
    //some calculations over value_of_A,
    //so it is not anymore the same as in variable1
}

variable2 = value_of_A;
```

When I compare `variable1` and `variable2` they are the same ALL THE TIME. I have tried new class so a setter can store the value, methods, all type of variable definitions etc.
Possible solution so far: to write `variable1` to a file, and then read it after the for loop. This should work, but any other solution?

Comment: show the code of your for loop, as well as the comparison of the two variables.

Comment: Show the code you have not the pseudocode for easy investigation

Comment: well, my guess is, you are comparing Objects with == and not with .equals()

Comment: Sounds like the used types are "reference types", so `variable1`, `variable2` and `value_of_A` always refer to the same object. So please post your real code (like Eran suggested).

Comment: @nafas, can you please pay more attention during your reviews and avoid approving _bad_ edit suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I didnt know the for loop {.. } statement

Answer (score 2):

I guess your problem is that you are working with objects, and in Java objects are passed by reference. It means, that you may have one object and two variables referencing it, and when you change the object via the first reference variable (`variable1`), the second reference variable (`variable2`) now gives you access to the same object, that has changed. Your solution is to create a new object inside your loop and assign a reference to this new object to your `variable2`, so that you will have to distinct objects with a single reference to each one of them.

```
// suppose this is the class you are working with
public class SomeObject {
    private String nya;

    public SomeObject(String value) {
        nya = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return nya;
    }

    public void changeByValue(int value) {
        nya += "Adding value: " + value;
    }
}

// and here comes the code that changes the object
// we assign the first variable the original object
SomeObject variable1 = someObject;
// but we do not assign the same object to the second one,
// instead we create the identical, but new object
SomeObject variable2 = new SomeObject(someObject.getValue());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // here we change the second (new) object, so the original stays the same
    variable2.changeValueBy(i);
}
System.out.println(variable1 == variable2);      // false
System.out.println(variable1.equals(variable2)); // depends on implementation
```

Comment: Hi, this sounds sensitive, but have no idea how to implement it. Can you give an example, pls?

Comment: Example added, check this out

Answer (score 1):

In Java, when working with objects, you're actually just having a reference to that object. That means, if you have something like this

```
SomeObject o1 = new SomeObject();
SomeObject o2 = o1;
```

then `o1` and `o2` point to the same object, thus changes made in `o1` are also affecting `o2`. This is called [Aliasing](http://www.vias.org/javacourse/chap08_09.html).

In order to compare two different objects you could for example use a **copy** of your object before changing it in your `for` loop.

```
// This is the object we want to work on.
SomeObject changing = new SomeObject();

// Copy-Constructor, where you assign the fields of 'changing' to a new object.
// This new object will have the same values as 'changing', but is actually a new reference.
SomeObject o1 = new SomeObject(changing); 

for loop {
    // This operation alters 'changing'.
    someOperationOn(changing);
}

// Again, a copy constructor, if you want to have another, different reference.
SomeObject o2 = new SomeObject(changing);
```

Now you have two objects `o1` and `o2` which doesn't affect each other anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your variables? It seems to me that it is a "by value" vs "by reference" issue. Look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188690/setting-equal-in-java-by-value-or-reference).
Essentially, depending on the type of your variable, the "=" followed by calculations does not create a new object. You just have one more reference to the same object in memory.